# Как узнать путь к программе например calc.exe?

Tags: c#, windows-10

Например в cmd можно запустить написав calc.exe

Реальный же его путь

`c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe`

Как в c# узнать путь calc.exe?

Comment: Процесс уже запущен или вам нужно его запустить? Опишите начальные условия подробнее

Comment: не похоже это на реальный путь calc, почитайте для чего используется папка WinSxS, приложения не должны из нее запускаться. пути по которым ищутся стандартные программы прописаны в переменной окружения PATH

Comment: Процесс не запущен. Мне нужно только получить полный путь до calc.exe по его названию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запуск программы по названию его *.exe осуществляется благодаря переменным среды, где указаны директории для поиска исполняемых файлов.

Соотвественно, все что тебе надо- это пройти по переменным среды через `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`, а затем по директориям с файлами.

Но не все программы туда прописываются.

Есть варианты с реестром:

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
{
    foreach(string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
        }
    }
}
```

и с WMI:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
foreach(ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"]);
}
```

Однако, если программа не устанавливалась, а просто запускался какой-то EXE файл, то ты вряд ли найдешь где-нибудь запись о ней=> придется искать полным перебором всех дисков и директорий.

Comment: как использовать `ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");` для calc.exe ?

Comment: Проитерировать результат метода и сопоставить с известным именем. Однако, я сомневаюсь, что он там есть, на сколько я помню, этот WMI запрос отражает то, что отражается "Установка и удаление программ", а там калькулятора нет.

Comment: откуда cmd берёт пути стандартных программ?

Comment: В переменной среды указаны директории для поиска

Comment: Это переменная среды `PATH`. Посмотреть значение можно в `Панель управления\Система и безопасность\Система` - `Дополнительные параметры системы - Дополнительно - Переменные среды`